# does calling command-line utility from an application create safety issues?

Tags: windows, macos, security, command-line

I would like to know if there are dangerous safety/security issues when a application is designed to call a command-line utility that opens a PDF file and yields some information in text files or images.

Comment: Such a general scenario cannot be assessed from a security point of view. You need to be specific.

Comment: Calling an external program can be done in a safe way, but the answer depends very much on the manner in which the call is done, the command being called and the platform.

Comment: my scenario is: calling a command-line utility that opens a pdf file and yields some information in text files or images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS command injection comes to mind. If the user is able to control part of the command line (e.g. "AcroRd32.exe file.pdf") If the attacker can control the name of the file, then you have to add strong white-list validation, so that "AcroRd32.exe file.pdf && format C: && rem .pdf" cannot be injected for example

Comment: The application has a string inside the code (has to be crtyptated?) that could be hard-wired but it is likely to be in the preferences (bad idea?) that represents the command to call the utility.After the call the application just read the created files but does not execute anything. The command includes compound strings to create the suitable parameters. The application doesn't hide the fact that it calls the utility. So my concern is that this design feature could make the application intrinsically unsecure. How can avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling a command line utility presents extra security concerns: Your application is now only as secure as the command line utility.

As an example, if there is a buffer overflow in the utility, then an attacher might be able to exploit it via your application.

Comment: what about calling a command-line utility that opens a pdf file and yields some information in text files or images? However my main concern is about possible flaws in my application.

Comment: Couldn't you say exactly the same thing whether it was a command line utility or built into the application code?

Comment: @Martin-Geisler So if a weakness of the utility is discovered or known and an attacker knows that my program calls the utility then can he/she  decide to exploit it and no mean to avoid it?

Comment: @tenfour: right, there could certainly also be a bug in the application code. It's a tradeoff: with your own code you invest more time but can take steps to ensure that there are no buffer overflows etc. With a third-party library/utility you have to trust someone else to make it secure. On the other hand, it might be that there is a big community behind the utility and so you trust it more than your own code.

Comment: @P5music: well, if the attacker can make you execute the utility with a malicious PDF file, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

No-one yet seems to have mentioned the most obvious attack. If I know you're calling an application (eg) 'c:\program files\acrord32.exe', then I can replace that
with a malware executable and wait for something to call it.

Having said that though, if I have access to the operating system to make a change like this, then all bets are off. I could just as easily run the malware, install a key logger, etc etc.

If however the system is fairly protected from alteration and your users are remotely using this application (such as a web app?) then you can help protect exploits like this
by using a known and trusted version of the executable, and generating/checking an md5 sum of the executable before using it. This helps ensure that the program has not been modified/replaced

Comment: thx @PaulG the checksum seems to be a very good solution when a replacement of the executable is feared. Are there other possible issues, I mean, is it possible that another command is issued instead of the one my application sends to system by interposing a sort of man-in-the-middle in the system memory? no network involved.

Comment: @P5music. If the attacker has physical access to the machine, then anything is possible. You possibly need to consider (and clarify for us) the who/why/what. Who your attacker is, why they would want to attack your system or what they might gain. If your question is regarding a desktop app, then calling external programs is no more dangerous than anything else the user/attacker could do to his/her own desktop machine.

Comment: All answers contribute more good points. @P5music : what you need to realize is that people get PhDs researching system vulnerabilities. There is no easy answer, and there is no perfect fool-proof, one-size-fits all answer. Protection of systems is a constantly moving target. If you're concerned about this for a production system, and it affects your income or reputation, you need at least read a book, maybe 3-4, just to understand the basics of how your systems can be compromised. Or you may need the services of a specialist. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The main security vulnerability related to doing so: [Path Manipulation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

(The other posters all raise valid security issues with PDF files)

PDF files are well know carriers of back-door access to systems. BUT it is the program that reads the file that is actually attacking your system, using the instructions that it finds in the PDF file.

So if you're using AcroRd32.exe, or any other know insecure .exe to 'yield(s) some information in text files or images.' then you're still allowing the malicious code in the PDF file to be executed.

If you can use a true text-parsing system to extract the data, then there is no mechanism that can provide a path for malicious code execution. I know there are extensions to the perl language used for parsing text out of PDF files, AND there probably many others.

I hope this helps.